# How to make camera not go through the walls and objects in Unity3d?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

I am creating a third-person android 3d game in unity. I have set up a **free look on touch** script to move the camera view around the player. Below is the code. But the camera following my player is moving through the walls and objects coming in between the player and the camera. I want the camera to adjust itself if it bumps into an object (Camera is not a child of my player).
Things I have tried but did not work:

1. Applying a box collider/rigidbody/material to the camera
2. Making an empty gameobject parent of camera and applying box collider/rigidbody/material to that gameobject
3. Making the camera clipping angle (near) < 0.3 This only works for 1st person but not for 3rd person.

I guess raycasting can be of help but I don't know how to implement it. Any suggestion would be of great help!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson;

public class ThirdPersonInput : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    public FixedJoystick LeftJoystick;
    public FixedButton Button;
    public FixedTouchField TouchField;

    protected ThirdPersonUserControl Control;
    protected float CameraAngle;
    protected float CameraAngleSpeed = 0.2f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Control = GetComponent<ThirdPersonUserControl>();
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Control.m_Jump = Button.Pressed;
        Control.Hinput = LeftJoystick.Direction.x;
        Control.Vinput = LeftJoystick.Direction.y;

        CameraAngle += TouchField.TouchDist.x * CameraAngleSpeed;

        Camera.main.transform.position = transform.position + Quaternion.AngleAxis(CameraAngle, Vector3.up) * new Vector3(0, 3, -3);
        Camera.main.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(transform.position + Vector3.up * 2f - Camera.main.transform.position, Vector3.up);
    }
}
```

Comment: Look for `SpringArmComponent`. You will apply it on the player (object) and put camera under it. This "invisible arm" will handle if there is anything between player and camera OR if the camera is going through objects, and instead updates camera position to avoid it. NOTE: This is not an official Unity component (released by*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be much convenient if you tried using cinemachine. Inside the cinemachine, there is a component called Cinemachine collider. Which will help you to solve this issue. Also, there are a bunch of other features to try.

Comment: Using Cinemachine and Cinemachine collider worked for me. In addition, there are many more features available in Cinemachine which are not there in the normal camera settings.